# torch.einsum 'RuntimeError: dimension mismatch for operand 0: equation 4 tensor 2'

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, gradient, numpy-einsum

I'm trying to manually calculate a gradient of a matrix and I can do it by using numpy but I don't know to do the same thing in pytorch. 
the equation in NumPy is

```
def grad(A, W0, W1, X):
    dim = A.shape
    assert len(dim) == 2
    A_rows = dim[0]
    A_cols = dim[1]    
    gradient = (np.einsum('ik, jl', np.eye(A_cols, A_rows), (((A).dot(X)).dot(W0)).dot(W1).T) + np.einsum('ik, jl', A, ((X).dot(W0)).dot(W1).T))
    return gradient
```

I wrote a function in pytorch but it's giving me an error saying 'RuntimeError: dimension mismatch for operand 0: equation 4 tensor 2'

The function I wrote using pytorch is

```
def torch_grad(A, W0, W1, X):
    dim = A.shape
    A_rows = dim[0]
    A_cols = dim[1]
    W0W1 = torch.mm(W0, W1)
    AX = torch.mm(A, X)
    AXW0W1 = torch.mm(AX, W0W1)
    XW0W1 = torch.mm(X, W0W1)
    print(torch.eye(A_cols, A_rows).shape, torch.t(AXW0W1).shape)
    e1 = torch.einsum('ik jl', torch.eye(A_cols, A_rows), torch.t(AXW0W1))
    e2 = torch.einsum('ik, jl', A, torch.t(XW0W1))
    return e1 + e2
```

I would appreciate if someone can show me how to implement the numpy code in pytorch.
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry the gradient I'm trying to calculate is with respect to A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma in the first `torch.einsum` call.

```py
e1 = torch.einsum('ik, jl', torch.eye(A_cols, A_rows), torch.t(AXW0W1))
```

Besides the typo, that's not how the gradients with respect to `A` are calculated, and it fails when `A` and `AX` have different sizes, which would be otherwise valid for the forward pass. For the `e1`, that should be a matrix multiplication, maybe that was your intention, in which case the `torch.einsum` should be `'ik, kl'`, but that's just an overly complicated way to perform a matrix multiplication and using `torch.mm` is simpler and more efficient. And the `e2` is not involved in anything calculation that was performed with respect to `A`, therefore it is not part of gradients.

```py
def torch_grad(A, W0, W1, X):
    # Forward
    W0W1 = torch.mm(W0, W1)
    AX = torch.mm(A, X)
    AXW0W1 = torch.mm(AX, W0W1)
    XW0W1 = torch.mm(X, W0W1)

    # Backward / Gradients
    rows, cols = AXW0W1.size()
    grad_AX = torch.mm(torch.eye(rows, cols), W0W1.t())
    grad_A = torch.mm(grad_AX, X.t())
    return grad_A

# Autograd version to verify that the gradients are correct
def torch_autograd(A, W0, W1, X):
    # Forward
    W0W1 = torch.mm(W0, W1)
    AX = torch.mm(A, X)
    AXW0W1 = torch.mm(AX, W0W1)
    XW0W1 = torch.mm(X, W0W1)
    
    # Backward / Gradients
    rows, cols = AXW0W1.size()
    AXW0W1.backward(torch.eye(rows, cols))
    return A.grad

# requires_grad=True for the autograd version to track
# gradients with respect to A
A = torch.randn(3, 4, requires_grad=True)
X = torch.randn(4, 5)
W0 = torch.randn(5, 6)
W1 = torch.randn(6, 5)

grad_result = torch_grad(A, W0, W1, X)
autograd_result = torch_autograd(A, W0, W1, X)

torch.equal(grad_result, autograd_result) # => True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was also wondering how to calculate the gradient of A*A*X*W0*W1 w.r.t to A. I'm now not so confident about my math.

Comment: [PyTorch - Tutorial: Learning PyTorch with Examples](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html#pytorch-tensors) shows an example how to calculate the gradients for a simple feed forward neural network with ReLU.